# how do I write the function for getting different background image and text upon clicking its designated button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am aware of the script that calls the text according to its button, but I have no clue how I can place a background image on that text. My plan is that the background image can also change according to the button that was clicked.  Here is what I've done so far...

This is actually for a school project and I want it to be as action-oriented or somewhat interactive in a way with just functions and methods. I also wanted to add another cell table and just place an image there with some texts just like a gaming avatar profile.

```js
function myFunction(elem) {
  var x = document.getElementById("js-description");
  var description = elem.getAttribute('data-description');
  x.innerHTML = description;
  var button = document.getElementsByClassName('js-button');
  for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].classList.remove('active-buton');
  }
  elem.classList.add('active-button');
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #190a48;
  margin: 0;
}

.btn-group button {
  font-family: SF;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  /* Green background */
  border: 1px solid #504c7c;
  /* Green border */
  color: white;
  /* White text */
  padding: 2.5% 1%;
  /* Some padding */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Pointer/hand icon */
  width: 15vw;
  height: 6vw;
  /* Set a width if needed */
  display: block;
  /* Make the buttons appear below each other */
  margin-left: 20%;
  border-radius: 4%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 6px 12px #544e88, inset -1px -10px 5px #2e2d3a, 1px 2px 1px #2e2d3a;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 6px 12px #544e88, inset -1px -10px 5px #2e2d3a, 1px 2px 1px #2e2d3a;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 6px 12px #544e88, inset -1px -10px 5px #2e2d3a, 1px 2px 1px #2e2d3a;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: none;
  /* Prevent double borders */
}

.active-button:hover {
  background-color: #83a1a7;
}

.description {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: St;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" width=1000px; style="border: 7px solid #040434;">
      <div id="js-description" class="description">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4" height=450px; class="imgxbtn" style="transparent;">
      <div class="js-button btn-group">
        <button data-description="Vivamus, moriendum est" onclick="myFunction(this)">   HOBBY    </button>
        <button data-description="Forsan et haec olim meminisse iuvabit" onclick="myFunction(this)">   MEMORY     </button>
        <button data-description="Sapere aude" onclick="myFunction(this)">    
       CONQUEST    </button>
        <button data-description="Audentes fortuna iuvat" onclick="myFunction(this)">    AMBITION  </button>
        <button data-description="Ad astra per aspera" onclick="myFunction(this)">    TARGET    </button>
      </div>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td rowspan="3" height=250px; style="border: 5px solid #040434; 
      opacity:35%; 
      background-color: #9a5eaa;">content</td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please make sure to take the [tour] and read [ask] in order to get started with this community. Nobody will be able to help you because you are talking about code that you forgot to add to you question. Please edit your question and add a code example that shows your current efforts in solving this issue.

Comment: thank you, lupz!  This could have been a disaster if it weren't for your concern :)

Comment: Tables are elements to display tabular data. Abusing them to implement page layouts is considered a bad practice. Nowadays we can use `flex` or `grid` layouts. Have a look at those.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You can use the same aproach for the background image as you already do for the description text. Just define another data-attribute with your image-url and set the respective CSS property like this:

```js
function onButtonClick() {
  var descriptionElement = document.getElementById("description");
  
  descriptionElement.innerHTML = event.target.dataset.description;
  descriptionElement.style['background-image'] = event.target.dataset.backgroundImage;
}
```

```html
<div id="description">Press one of the buttons below.</div>

<button
  data-description="First description"
  data-background-image="linear-gradient(red, orange)"
  onclick="onButtonClick()">first</button>
<button
  data-description="Second description"
  data-background-image="linear-gradient(teal, green)"
  onclick="onButtonClick()">second</button>
```

I use gradients here because I don't have an image at hand. To use an actual image you can specify it like `data-background-image="url('path/to/your/image')"`.

Comment: hi! thank you so much! it worked but I cant seem to manipulate the size of the image background. Do I create a CSS for it?

Comment: Yes, that is a job for CSS. There are a lot of properties you can use. Things like repeating backgrounds, background positions and sizes. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background to get started with further styling. Happy coding!